# Create a new variable on condition of two other variables

Tags: python, for-loop

I have two binary variables in the dataframe labels:

```
target1=[0,1,0,0,0.....1]
target2=[1,1,0,0,0.....0]
```

And I want to create a third variable that:

> 1. if target1=0 and target2=0, T=0,
> 2. if target1=1 and target2=0, T=1,
> 3. if target1=0 and target2=1, T=2,
> 4. if target1=1 and target2=1, T=3.

```
for i in range(len(labels)):
    if target1[i]==0 and target2[i]==0:
        labels['T']=0
    elif target1[i]==1 and target2[i]==0:
        labels['T']=1
    elif target1[i]==0 and target2[i]==1:
        labels['T']=2
    else:
        labels['T']=3
```

for some reason, the only outcome for  is 0. I'm not sure what went wrong.

Comment: What is `labels`? You keep overwriting `labels['T']` within the `for` loop. By the way you could've simply written `labels['T'] = target1[i] + 2 * target2[i]`

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Comment: Well, I am surprised. It is exactly same as your code, only shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to change

```
for i in range(len(labels)):
```

to

```
for i in range(len(target1)):
```

Otherwise you run loop only once or whatever you have items in labels